# Combine 2 JavaScript RegEx groups with AND and quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

Unfortunately I try in vain to write a suitable JavaScript RegEx, which matches the following case:

1. it is matched to a singleline string, not a multiline.
2. **ONLY** positive if the string **contains less than 6 words**
3. **AND** if it **contains any of the words "There", "This", "Dog"**.

The RegEx for the 2 point is probably:

`^(\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,4}\s*)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xgbOTQ/1)

The RegEx for the 3 point is probably:

`^(?=.*(There\b|\This\b|\bDog)).*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/O1iUzs/2)

Now I have the problem to combine this 2 regex into one. I've tried something like: 
`^(\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,5}\s*)(?=.*(There\b|\bThis\b|Dog)).*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Jxtxa/2)

How I can combine there 2 RegEx correctly?

Some Examples:

`Hello I am under 6 words` -> negative, no trigger word

`Hello I am under dog words` -> positive under 6 words + trigger word (dog)

`Hello I am dog but with a longer string` -> negative because more then 6 words

`Dog` -> positive, under 6 words + trigger word(dog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put the lookahead from the second regex after `^` in the first regex and use word boundaries around the alternation:

```
^(?=.*\b(?:There|This|Dog)\b)\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,5}\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rAOGtE/2). Note the case insensitive modifier in the demo (`/^(?=.*\b(?:There|This|Dog)\b)\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){1,5}\s*$/i`).

It matches strings with 6 words or less that must contain `There`, `This` or `Dog` as whole words.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D.*%5Cb(%3F%3AThere%7CThis%7CDog)%5Cb)%5Cs*%5CS%2B(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5CS%2B)%7B1%2C5%7D%5Cs*%24):

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much!